# How to restore Session by session_id in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to restore a session with an existing session ID. So far unfortunately without success.

things that have not worked:

- delete session and set new session with `session_start()`
- delete session cookie and set a new one
- change security configuration in Session Lib

does anyone have another idea?

Comment: Can you elobarate more about your question

Comment: I want transfer a session for example in to another browser. And in the new browser i try to continue the session.

Comment: You cant. Session set for browser. You can move to another browser

Comment: I'm sure that there must be one away